# How to check if WiFi connection has internet on Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-internet

I am trying to find a way to check if my current WiFi connection has internet.

Using the usual option of ping or trying to reach a site won't work if I also have mobile data open because it will return true due to that.

Comment: check if it is connected to wifi or mobile network first then ping.

Comment: @iamanbansal Problem is that it can be connected to both

Answer (score 0):

Check [hasTransport](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#hastransport) (from [NetworkCapabilities](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/NetworkCapabilities))

You can use the value `TRANSPORT_WIFI` to test WIFI connection

```kotlin
connection.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
```

I also found some gists, hope they can help you

[Check Internet Connection [API21+][API29+ supported] Lifecycle aware](https://gist.github.com/chydee/b542119cfcaf2f345adb0b2776878236)

[Class to check the Connectivity and Internet Access of an Android device.](https://gist.github.com/kibotu/c3e57522f489d2e4d0d38c261f5b0220)

Comment: What is the `connection` api?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me. Note: if cellular data is valid in your application then you can add it to the last line.

```
    private static boolean isNetworkAvailable(@NonNull Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Network nw = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
    if (nw == null) return false;
    NetworkCapabilities actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw);
    return actNw != null && (actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) ||
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET));
}
```